# renewing uk passport after 30 years away

Tags: passport

I am a UK citizen with a British Passport. I married a French girl and moved to France 30 years ago. Can I now renew my old UK passport and where do I go to get it renewed?I still have my old passport.

Comment: Has your passport expired?

Comment: Are you in the UK or France? Have you looked at https://www.gov.uk/renew-adult-passport or https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports

Comment: @Traveller it seems as though the age of the former passport is likely to mean that the application will be handled as a "first passport" application rather than a renewal.  This isn't obvious from the page you linked to, but the [online tool](https://www.gov.uk/apply-renew-passport) gives this result if you say that the passport was issued 30 years ago, and the [first adult passport](https://www.gov.uk/apply-first-adult-passport) page says, somewhat ambiguously, that "you can also apply if your last UK passport was an old handwritten blue or black one."

Answer (score 2):

The definitive answer is available on the government web site: https://www.gov.uk/overseas-passports

This asks a number of questions.  Assuming your old passport has expired, it looks like you will have to apply for a brand new passport from scratch.  This may involve a passport interview.  I *think* you can do these at your nearest UK consulate.